# Display elments (without redundancy) of list in list stream in Java

Tags: java, list, stream, java-stream

I have a list of people who have :
List of hobbies {games, ski, football ...)
height
weight
YearOfBirth

I want to display the list (without redundancy) of the hobbies of the 5 heaviest of the 20 largest individuals born in 1999

I have a list of streams:

```
List<String> question7 = ListPerson.stream()
     .filter( p -> p.getDateDeNaissance().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate().getYear() == 1999)
     .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(p -> ((person) p).getHeight()).reversed())
     .limit(20)
     .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(p -> ((Individu) p).getWeight()).reversed())
     .limit(5)
     .map(s->s.getListHobbys())            
     .flatMap(Collection::stream)   
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I don't have what I want and there is redundancy. Can someone ask me who I can do that

Comment: I recommend using [`Stream::distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct()).

Comment: i resolved it like that  `.flatMap(Collection::stream).distinct() `

Comment: Just call it. It's an intermediate stream operation.

Comment: yes i do that thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions.

Your overall logic is correct (albeit what I believe to be a typo in the second sort).  You use `Individu` and it should be `Person` or whatever your class is.

But instead of casting in the Comparators you can specify a witness and do it as follows:

```
List<String> question7 = listPerson.stream()
        .filter( p -> p.getDateDeNaissance().toInstant()
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .toLocalDate().getYear() == 1999)
        .sorted(Comparator.<Person>comparingDouble(p->p.getHeight())
                .reversed())
        .limit(20)
        .sorted(Comparator.<Person>comparingDouble(p->p.getWeight())
                .reversed())
        .limit(5).map(p->p.getListHobbys())
        .flatMap(Collection::stream).distinct().toList();
```

Or you can eliminate the witness and the lambda by specifying method references

```
List<String> question7 = listPerson.stream()
        .filter( p -> p.getDateDeNaissance().toInstant()
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .toLocalDate().getYear() == 1999)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Person::getHeight)
                .reversed())
        .limit(20)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Person::getWeight)
                .reversed())
        .limit(5).map(Person::getListHobbys)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream).distinct().toList();
```

But there is nothing wrong with the way you did it and the choice is yours.